# ibm portlet 8.0 (JSR 286) device detection

Tags: portlet, jsr286

I've been working on a IBM portal 8.0 and JSR 286. My requirement is to detect whether the request is coming from a PC Browser or Mobile or Tablet. I'm not using Web experience factory. It is just basic portlet project.

Please someone suggest is there any way (any helper classes or any other mechanism) for the device detection in IBM Portlet 8 (JSR286).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in your portlet's jsp to detect the [type of device](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/#.UHLJdpjMhMc). Otherwise there are other options available at [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/)

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I've already implemented the solution you have suggested; but I want a portal specific solution. I came to know that IBM Portal 8.0 has got some functionality to detect the device type automatically with some configuration and code; I wish to make use of any such portal specific functionality to detect device type.

Comment: Try [IBM Mobile Portal Accelerator](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Mobile+Portal+Accelerator+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Introduction_to_IBM_Mobile_Portal_Acceleratormpa8&content=pdcontent)